# How to sort and limit an SQL table by sum of a numerical column grouped by multiple categories?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following SQL table:

| Country | ProductID | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 1 | 10 |
| US | 2 | 20 |
| GB | 3 | 25 |
| GB | 4 | 40 |
| US | 1 | 10 |
| US | 1 | 10 |
| DE | 2 | 20 |
| DE | 2 | 20 |

I want to see the two most profitable (per sum of price) "*ProductID*" per "*Country*" (sorted by Sum per "*Country*") like this:

| Country | ProductID | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 4 | 40 |
| US | 1 | 30 |
| GB | 4 | 40 |
| GB | 3 | 25 |
| DE | 2 | 20 |

How can I perform this?

Comment: Total sum per country, or just the sum of the two most profitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `RANK` here in conjunction with an aggregation by country and product:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Country, ProductID, SUM(Price) AS Sum,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY SUM(Price) DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Country, ProductID
)

SELECT Country, ProductID, Sum
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 2
ORDER BY Country, rnk;
```